# Will jdk/jre 5.0 64 bit download for windows AMD work with Windows x86?

Tags: 64-bit, java

I could not find a download link for 64 bit jdk/jre 5.0 for Windows x86. The download link says it is for Windows 64-bit AMD.

We are moving to Windows 7 64-bit x86. I am looking for jdk/jre 5.0 64 bit download.

Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

IIRC the regular 64-bit Intel CPUs are using the same instruction set for 64-bit mode as the AMD CPUs so that JDK should work.